# Display the selection of the combo Box in the Selection panel's text field

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am trying to display the selection of the combo Box in the Selection panel's text field

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
  import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JComboBox;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;

 public class Department extends JFrame {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public static final String Art = "Art";

 public static final String Biology = "Biology";

 public static final String Chemistry = "Chemistry";

 public static final String Computer_Science = "Computer_Science";
    public static final String Economics = "Economics";

     public static final String History = "History";

     public static final String Music = "Music";

    public static final String Philosophy = "Philosophy";
    public static final String Physics = "Physics";

     public static final String Psycholgy = "Psychology";
       public static final String Psychology = "Psychology";

  //constructor
  public Department() {
   setSize(700, 150);

  setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  setVisible(true);// making the frame visible

  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setTitle("Banner Self Service For Brahmbhatt");
```

TermPanel();

```
}

//400 width and 500 height
    //private method with components
        private void TermPanel() {

//base panel
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();

 panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

 panel.setSize(700, 190);
 panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

 JPanel selectionPanel = new JPanel();
 selectionPanel.setSize(10, 10);

 selectionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
 JTextField zodiacSign = new JTextField(10);

//adding the instructions for creating the birthday panel
JPanel birthdayPanel = new JPanel();
```

//uSING Grid layout
     birthdayPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
     birthdayPanel.add(new JLabel("Select A Department: "));

```
 birthdayPanel.setBackground(new Color(250, 230, 230));
 String[] choices = { "","Art","Biology", 
"Chemistry","Computer_Science","Economics","English", "History", "Music", 
"Mathematics", "Philosophy", "Physics", "Psychology"};

//Creating a comboBox
 final JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(choices);
 cb.setVisible(true);

 birthdayPanel.add(cb);
 panel.add(birthdayPanel);

 getContentPane().add(panel);
 JTextField textField = null;


  //Panels for the selection term field
 zodiacSign.setEnabled(true);//so that no one can use it as input field 
 zodiacSign.setEditable(true);//so that no one can edit the zodiac sign

 selectionPanel.add(zodiacSign); // adding the zodiacsign textfield to panel
 zodiacSign.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));   //setting minimu 
 dimensions for the zodiac panel
 zodiacSign.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 150));     //setting minimum 
  dimensions for the zodia

 selectionPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your Selection 
    is"));
 selectionPanel.setBackground(new Color(250, 230, 230));
 panel.add(selectionPanel);
```

// Adds an action listener
cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
    Object selected = cb.getSelectedItem();
    textField.setText((String) cb.getSelectedItem());
}
```

});

getContentPane().add(panel);

}

}

Comment: And the problem is? Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: (1-) You still haven't stated what the problem is. 2) The code you posted is not formatted. Learn how to use the forum properly when posting code is you want people to read it. 3) That is not a `MCVE`. Your question is about a combo box and setting text in a panel. So create a simple `MCVE`. All you need is a frame with a combo box and a text field. Then you add an ActionLIstener to the combo box to update the text field when an item is selected. The whole program will be about 20-25 lines of code which makes it easy to debug. Once you understand the basic concept you fix your real code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your other code, so I guess you forgot to add the listener to the JComboBox.
If this method is declared in an `ActionListener` object, you can do this to add this listener to your `JComboBox`

```
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(); //sample declaration
cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: i edited the code, can you help me now. Thanks for your help

Comment: `JTextField textField = null;` Why is your textField null?

Comment: Also, by convention your constants names  should be capitalized like ART, your method names should start with a lowercase letter and the first letter of each word after should be uppercase, like `private void TermPanel()` should be `private void termPanel()`. Your method name should describe what the method does. So `initialize()` would be a better name for `termPanel()`. Hope my comment helps.